# Insert data from Json table to the view that has been already created with exec in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, exec

I have a problem, I have to insert data from a Json that stored in a table that has jus one field then insert them directly to the view but my code has a error and I can't fix that.
My code is this(but it has error):

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[viewJson]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OpenJson NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT * FROM FoodSara_tbl FOR JSON AUTO) -- Make Json from Original Table

SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@OpenJson)

WITH (FID INT,
Fname NVARCHAR(50),
Ftype NVARCHAR(20),
Fcount INT,
Fdate VARCHAR(400),
Fregion NVARCHAR(50),
Fdescription NVARCHAR(100)) AS SM


EXEC('CREATE VIEW Json1 AS SELECT * FROM SM')

END
```

my first table that has Json data:

```
|  JsonOutPut                                                                   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|[{"FID":1,"Fname":"cake","Fcount":5,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK"},...]  |
```

my view should be like this:

```
| FID | Fname | Fcount| FDate    | Fregion |
|-----|-------|-------|----------|---------|
|  1  | cake  |   5   |2020-02-13|    UK   |
```

I don't want create new table!

I have an eeror: Incorrect syntax near 'Json1'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert JSON object to SQL Server 2016 as nvarchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323946/how-to-insert-json-object-to-sql-server-2016-as-nvarchar)

Comment: Also review, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297060/json-nested-object-to-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: No, as I said I wanna insert into the view, the first link insert to the table

Comment: So don't use the INSERT INTO clause. Everything else in both links seems relevant.